# TO initiate Python shell

Tags: python

You can use subprocess.call("/usr/bin/python") to open Python shell within a piece of Python code. Now my question is is it possible to predefine some variables/functions before initialization of this shell? In other words, inside Python code, I can define a bunch of useful variables and functions and I want them to be available in the Python shell opened later by subprocess call. It is useful in the sense that sometimes you want a customized Python shell to test your environment.

Comment: As an aside, it's a good idea to use `sys.executable` instead of hard coding the path to the Python binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `-i` switch. This will run a script, and then drop into the interpreter for interactive use.

```
python -i scriptname.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but I wouldn't do it this way anyways; I'd use [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's something that it's possible and it's useful. In fact, that's something that django provides with the `python manage.py shell` command.

Looking at the [source code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/shell.py) for this command should be helpful not only as an example to open a shell with some default configuration, but also to use any shell you like ([ipython](http://ipython.org/), [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) or the default one).